# I have a bug in my UserForm code that inserts a saved picture into excel to the next cell down

Tags: vba, excel

I asked this question a few weeks ago and it got "sort of" solved but there are still bugs. Here is what I need to happen:

I have a Excel Sheet and have created a UserForm that has a InkPicture Box and is set to allow a person to open the user form and draw their signature. There is a CommandButton assigned to take the signature and save it from the clipboard onto the PC. I Have another CommandButton assigned to retrieve said saved picture from the PC path and bring it back to a specific sheet in my workbook and insert it at a specific cell.

My need is the following: I need the Code I'm using to update what cell it will insert the image at every time I click on the button. (In other words. I need the code to go from C3 to C50 on one digit increase every time I push the button and after it reaches revert back to C3)

The Bug I'm still having basically does three cells of perfect insert and then it gets stuck and inserts the rest of the pictures in the same cell. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ImgPath As String
Dim W As Double, H As Double
Dim L As Long, T As Long
Dim myArr() As Variant, myArrCounter As Long
Dim newRowNumb As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mobile POS Log Sheet")

'////////////////////////////////////////   This section will find the row of the bottom most shape in Column C
ReDim myArr(1 To 1)
myArrCounter = 0

For Each wshape In ws.Shapes
myArrCounter = myArrCounter + 1
If myArrCounter = 1 And wshape.TopLeftCell.Column = 3 Then
    myArr(myArrCounter) = wshape.TopLeftCell.row
Else:
    If wshape.TopLeftCell.Column = 3 And wshape.TopLeftCell.row > myArr(UBound(myArr)) Then
        ReDim Preserve myArr(1 To myArrCounter)
        myArr(myArrCounter) = wshape.TopLeftCell.row
    End If
End If
Next wshape
newRowNumb = myArr(UBound(myArr)) + 1 ' this adds two rows to place the new picure.  



'~~> This is my current pic file path
ImgPath = "C:\Users\raphaelo\Downloads\test.gif"


With ws
    W = 30                  '<~~ Width
    H = 11                  '<~~ Height
    L = .Range("c" & newRowNumb).Left   '<~~ This is what should be changing each time I run the command
    T = .Range("c" & newRowNumb).Top    '<~~ This is what should be changing each time I run the command
     '<~~ Both the L and T Range entries should change to the next cell (C3 to C4 to C5 and so on) One digit up every time I run the Command Code
     '<~~ Unless it's the Placement entry below?
    With .Pictures.Insert(ImgPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = W
            .Height = H
        End With
        .Left = L
        .Top = T
        .Placement = 1 '<~~ Not sure if this is the one that should change one digit up each time I run the Command instead?
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Odd that `.row` is not `.Row` - do you have a global variable with the name "row"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracking picure positions is tricky so I'd take a different approach:

```
Public Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    'Use Const for fixed values...
    Const PIC_FLAG As String = "PIC"
    Const IMG_PATH As String = "C:\_Stuff\test\test.png"
    Const MAX_ROW As Long = 50
    Const W As Long = 30
    Const H As Long = 11

    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mobile POS Log Sheet")

    Set c = ws.Range("C3")
    'find first empty cell
    Do While c.Value = PIC_FLAG And c.Row < MAX_ROW 
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    If c.Value = PIC_FLAG Then
        MsgBox "No rows left!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ws.Pictures.Insert(IMG_PATH)
         With .ShapeRange
             'if you lock the aspect ration then
             '  adjusting both W and H might give
             '  odd results...
             .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
             .Width = W
             .Height = H
         End With
         .Left = c.Left
         .Top = c.Top
         .Placement = 1
     End With
     c.Value = PIC_FLAG     '<< flag has pic
     c.Font.Color = vbWhite '<< hide the flag

End Sub
```